# Problem with links when transformin with XSLT

Tags: xslt

When I use XSLT to transform from one XHTML page to a new XHTML page, i can't get the A tags in the menu to work. Is there a way to get the correct source to the links when transforming in some way? Preciate some help and also tips to improve the code below. Thansk! :)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="//*[@id='mbSubMenu']/ul/li">
<li style="margin: 0; padding: 3px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">
<blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 5px; padding: 0">
 <a class="vanstermeny_underniva" href="{link}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
</blockquote>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Too many details are missing for making possible an answer to this "question".

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="vanstermeny_underniva">
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</a>
```

Try this.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't work the way I wanted. The value of href is the same as the text in the links. Not the correct value to the href!? Could it be done in some other way?

Comment: Not able to understand. href should contain the value of text in the link, right? Or you want something different. Give an example what you want as output.

Answer (score 0):

You need more detail as mentioned elsewhere. But what is clear is that you should use push instead pull in order to get all your data. Google 'xslt push' and read up on this. Here is a quick example:

XML

```
<div>
<div id ="mbSubMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blah</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div id="something">
    <a href="#">else</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">   
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//div[@id = 'mbSubMenu']" />
    </html> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```